# Cloudformation stack creation of bastion auto scaling group fails

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS cloud i start a quick start of TIBCO EMS but it fails on creation of bastion auto scaling group below the output of the console

need help.

Comment: the error msg ==>Embedded stack arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:599892971856:stack/TIBCO-EMS-BastionStack-PL9220EZUR6/6f0addd0-3ddd-11e8-94e5-50a68a05d0d1 was not successfully created: The following resource(s) failed to create: [BastionAutoScalingGroup].

Comment: template used attached in this link ==> https://community.tibco.com/questions/tibco-ems-quick-start-failed